# Create AutoMapper mapping with calculated value?

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to configure a simple AutoMapper mapping from an Entity Framework entity to a view model object. It mostly works but in the view model I have an int field to hold a count. This field does not exist in the source entity.

```
cfg.CreateMap<Feed, FeedVM>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Count, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Orders.Count()));
```

When I check the validity of the mapping I get the following error message:

> The following property on Feed cannot be mapped:
>
> Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the destination type Feed.
>   Context:
>   Mapping from type FeedVM to Feed

If I understand the Automapper syntax correctly I am mapping from Feed to FeedVM but the error message seems to indicate that I am mapping from FeedVM to Feed.

What should I be doing to map the value 42 to the Count field in FeedVM?

Comment: Voted to close this question, since in the comments of the accepted answer, OP realized a different error was occurring than the one in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `ResolveUsing`:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Feed, FeedVM>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.Count, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Orders.Count()));
```

Update

John indicates in the comment below that the mappings are correct, the problem lies in a mapping for another entity that is related to `Feed`. In that entity he is mapping both directions.

Comment: In an attempt to keep my example simple I might have over simplified. Rather then "42" I am doing a Linq query to pull a count of a related object. I m odified the code example accordingly.  Is UseValue still the right option?

Comment: Ahh, since I don't have your source code to try it out, can you use `ResolveUsing` instead of `MapFrom`? : `.ForMember(dest => dest.Count, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src => src.Orders.Count()));`

Comment: That throws the same validation error. I'll see if I can bring in a little bit more code to help make it clearer.

Comment: After some further testing I believe the mappings are correct. The problem lies in a mapping for another entity that is related to Feed. In that entity I am mapping both directions.